# How can I best retrieve location data from database by simplifying the data

Tags: postgresql, gis, simplify

I have a table with lat and long data and there are more than 10 million rows in the table. Table contains Time, DeviceID, lat, long columns.
By grouping lat and long data such as 39.88648368869136, 32.7210188424348 as 39.886483,32,721018, I simplified it as in the example below and counted how many points there are in which region.

```
select time_bucket('1 day', “time”) as time,
       “deviceID,
       round(lat::numeric,6)::double precision,
       round(long::numeric,6)::double precision,
       count(*) as numberOfPoint
from geoinfo
group by time, "nodeId", round(lat::numeric,6), round(lng::numeric,6)
order by time desc;
```

At the end, I get information like the one below.

| Time | id | latitude | longitude | numberOfPoint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | 1 | 39.000000 | 39.000000 | 5 |
| 01.01.2021 | 2 | 39.000000 | 39.000001 | 8 |
| ---- | ------ | ----- | ---- | ------ |
| 08.01.2021 | 1 | 39.000432 | 39.000012 | 9 |

My aim is to pull the data from the database as little and meaningfully as possible and show it on the map in an understandable way. (If I try to pull out all the data and show it on the map, the system gets clogged) I want to display it as a raster on the map, to color the points according to the density and to show the amount of points in each raster square.
My questions:

1. Is there a logic error in the above process?
2. Is there any chance of a better practice of simplifying and visualizing data instead of the above method(The most important problem here is how the data is pulled, that is, how the sql query is made).
   Note: We cannot use postgis for certain reasons and thank you for all your answers

Comment: Does the map have a specific resolution or can it be dynamically zoomed? If you have a map dimension (static or dynamic) and a grid resolution (your grid) then you can use an affine transformation (assuming the map has the same orientation as the grid).

Comment: @Patrick I am still undecided whether it is dynamic or static.  I took a look at affine transformation, but it doesn't seem to meet what I want, but it may be useful for me in the future.  Thank you for the answer. Also the solution I've found so far: it will reduce the amount of data  in a particular region by adding area restriction.  When the area gets bigger, I think I can get around this problem by using 5 or 4 instead of 6 in the above circular operation.

Comment: In general, you want to have a maximum number of points on your map in the vertical and the horizontal directions, say 10 in each direction. You can then take the extent of your map in each direction and divide by the number of points. That gives you your bins in latitude and longitude. In your query you can allocate tuples to each bin, then count the number of points. Does that sound like a solution?